# ASP.NET app access to UNC shared DB file works as IIS virtual directory but not as an IIS website

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, integrated-security

This one is killing me. I have an ASP.net (2.0 Framework) app that uses integrated security. IIS is setup appropriately and works fine as a virtual directory off the default website. My OLEDB connection (Jet 4.0) works fine and connects to a database file via network share (\GIS1\GIS Server - PublicWorks_StreetSigns).

BUT, when I create an IIS "website" and point it to the exact same home directory I get an error...

Error getting data from DBF. '\GIS1\GIS Server - PublicWorks_StreetSigns' is not a valid path.

Do I have to do something different in a website versus a virtual off the default website to make this work? I've triple checked the virtual settings against the website settings and everything is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The website is using the same app pool as the virtual directory that is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the identity of the application pool servicing each website. My guess is that the default identity of the app pool doesn't have permissions to that path.

Comment: Agree with John W. Also check the directory security settings; might be an impersonation problem.